# Proving a Recursion Using Induction

Tags: induction, recursion

I am trying to prove the following recursion.

$$a(n) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
n(a(n-1)+1) & \text{if } n \geq 1\\ 
0 & \text{if } n = 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

is the series definition of $a(n)$. using this, I need to prove that

$$ a(n) = n!\bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\bigg)$$

for $n \geq 1$ by induction on $n$.

I've found that the $n$ equals, for the first 5 terms, $2,5,16,65,326$. I think now I need to find a formula that describes these terms, and therefore $a(n)$. The problem is, I don't know where to start. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: You were given the formula for $a$ already. You need to prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(a(n)=n!\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\dfrac 1{k!}\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your induction step is:
\begin{align}
n \cdot a_{n-1} + n & = n(n-1)!\bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\bigg) + 1 \\
& = n!\bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\bigg) + n! \cdot \frac{1}{n!} \\
& = n!\bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)}!  + \frac{1}{n!}\bigg) \\
& = a_n
\end{align}
The base is easy. Then you're done. Read up on how induction works.

Answer (score 1):

For $m\ge1,$

If $a(m)=m!\left(\sum_{r=0^{m-}}\frac1{r!}\right)$

\begin{align}
a(m+1) & =(m+1)[a(m)+1] \\[6pt]
& =(m+1)[m!\left(\sum_{r=0^{m-}}\frac1{r!}\right)+1] \\[6pt]
& =(m+1)!\left(\sum_{r=0^{m-}}\frac1{r!}\right)+m+1 \\[6pt]
& =(m+1)!\left(\sum_{r=0^{m-}}\frac1{r!}\right)+\frac{(m+1)!}{m!}
\end{align}